# .NET Core 3 WPF detect if first run

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to detect when my program is updated and running for the first time. So I can show the changelog...

In .NET framework I did the following:

```
public static bool IsUpdated()
{
    return ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed && ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun;
}
```

**But in .NET Core `ApplicationDeployment` doesn't exists anymore...**

Comment: Why not write a marker to a config file / registry entry / database, etc? If the marker does not exist, it is a first run.

Comment: @Kei that is a possibility, and then I write the version number so if this is different I know it is the first run after an update...